# Функция srand()

Tags: случайные-числа

Изучаю ГПСЧ. Для генерации постоянно меняющегося сида при запуске `rand()` используют функцию `srand(time(null))`
С `time(null)` понятно - возвратит количество секунд после 01.01.1970. Например, если фактическая дата будет 01.01.1970 и 00:20 - покажет 1200 если не ошибаюсь.
А вот что покажет `srand(time(null))`? если `time(null)=1200`, Каким будет seed? В смысле какое число получится. Читал что ничего не возвращается, но этого не понял.
И как понять запуск ГПСЧ. Имеется ввиду включение программы или же 1-ократная генерация ПСЧ?

Comment: В ГПСЧ следующее значение обычно вычисляется на основании предыдущего. Запуск - это генерация того самого первого значения на основе которого будет вычисляться следующее. А seed сами посмотрите какой получится он зависит от алгоритма конкретного ГПСЧ который в свою очередь зависит от ОС и используемых библиотек

Comment: В конце концов вы можете вообще не инициализировать генератор, правда при этом при каждом запуске программы вы будете получать одну и ту же последовательность

Comment: А, вы имеете ввиду, что srand генерирует число на основе того или оного метода генерации ПСЧ, как например - на основе линейного конгруэнтного метода, метода фибоначи и т.д.?

Comment: А как ему еще генерировать, если в системе нет аппаратного генератора